# OAuth To .Net Core Api User Mapping

Tags: .net-core, oauth, jwt, openid-connect, asp.net-core-6.0

I work for a company that supports many applications, but for ease for users has an OAuth OIDC Single-Sign-On (IdentityServer4) so they can log in once and access many applications of ours. I have no problem configuring authorization to this OAuth with the returned JWT/Access Token.

But because our support footprint is so large, we have been told to handle roles, and user permissions at the application level. Here is where I am asking for feedback. I am currently developing a new API in .Net Core 6 (newbie to building APIs), and am wondering best practice for connecting a essentially third party OAuth, but also utilizing roles and permissions specific to the application.

The Identity Server returns a JWT/Access Token that is passed to API in form of bearer, but I need a mapping on the .net core backend to map the User contained in the JWT with a user within the application. Then the application can have separate mappings for roles/permissions, and utilize those roles as restrictions within the API, but I am not sure what best practice would be for this that also maintains the best security, while also achieving best performance. My thought was creating a middleware that creates and overrides userIdentity, but with that happening each call seems like unnecessary overhead. The other option is dual auth with cookie based auth that is set once, but am just unsure of best way, or what others have had success with. I know this must be a common flow that I am overthinking. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is common in many mature business systems to integrate identity and business data as you describe. There are two main techniques:

- Identity system reaches out to business data at the time of token issuance, to get custom claims to include in access tokens. This [Curity article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) explains the approach.
- APIs look up custom claims, eg from a database, when an access token is first received, then cache custom claims for subsequent requests with the same access token. See [this .NET code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/ClaimsCachingAuthorizer.cs#L37) of mine for one way to do this.

In both cases the end result should be that the API business logic gets a useful ClaimsPrincipal that enables the correct authorization, as in [this example class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/logic/services/CompanyService.cs).

Finally, from an information disclosure viewpoint, aim to avoid returning detailed claims in JWTs to internet clients. It is common to use [opaque access tokens](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/) instead, as a privacy preserving pattern.